# Service worker registration failing on Chrome Extension without error message

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a Hello World extension that consistantly fails to load in developer mode with the error message: `Service worker registration failed`. This extension works on other machines, but always fails on my work computer. I believe it has something to do with admin settings in Chrome but the admins aren't sure what would be causing the error - nothing in chrome://policy is obviously the culprit. I've tried changing the folder name of the extension to force a new ID and it still fails. I've also tried using the **--enable-logging=stderr** command line switch but didn't find any helpful log messages about the failure.

Is there any Chrome setting that could cause this (on my end or from admin policy) and/or is there a way to see additional logging as to why it's failing?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLeuW.png)

**background-wrapper.js**

```
try {
    importScripts("background.js");
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Remove parts of background.js until it works to find where the problem is.

Comment: I've commented out the entire file and still get the same issue. I'm sure it isn't the background.js file because it works in other environments, just not my company provided Chrome (or Edge or Canary).

Comment: Remove `./` maybe it triggers a bug in Chrome and it's unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Removed `./` but still the same issue. Anything policy related you can think of that could cause the registration to fail? Or any ways to see details on why it's failing? Appreciate your help!